# How do I assign the output of an arrow function in JS to a variable when it's embedded in an object?

Tags: javascript

I am using some javascript code from a public repo found at:

https://github.com/base62/base62.js

Where I am working to capture the output to slice for a date conversion. But for obvious reasons it tells me it is not a function when I attempt to slice the integer. A code sample is below. I will note via a comment where it has it causes me an error.

See below:

```
    const base62 = {
  charset:
    "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split(""),
  encode: (integer) => {
    if (integer === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    let s = [];
    while (integer > 0) {
      s = [base62.charset[integer % 62], ...s];
      integer = Math.floor(integer / 62);
    }
    return s.join("");
  },
  decode: (chars) =>
    chars
      .split("")
      .reverse()
      .reduce(
        (prev, curr, i) => prev + base62.charset.indexOf(curr) * 62 ** i,
        0
      ),
};

let sample = '3YY';

console.log(base62.decode(sample)); // the output should be 15312

// If I try to assign this to a variable and do the following an error is presented
let decodeMe = base62.decode(sample).slice(0, 4);
```

The error looks something like this:

**VM28714:1 Uncaught TypeError: base62.decode(sample).slice is not a function.**

I'm seeking some guidance on how to capture the output of the base62.decode(sample), which is 15312 so I can use later in the script.

Comment: You are trying to `slice` a number. Convert it to a string

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns a number, which does not have a `slice` method. Convert it to a string first:

```js
// multiple methods shown below:
String(base62.decode(sample)).slice(0, 4);
(base62.decode(sample) + '').slice(0, 4);
base62.decode(sample).toString().slice(0, 4);
```